# Exception handling is failing when exception is thrown in windows API

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch, magnification-api

I am calling a windows function MagSetWindowSource(windows magnifier API). For some reason it is throwing an exception. I want to catch this exception but I am unable to do so.
I tried

```
__try
{

    MagSetWindowSource()

}
__except(EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER)
{
}
```

and showed *an unhandled exception was encountered during a user callback* message.I tried all C++ exceptions flags (/EHa, /EHSc, etc) in Visual Studio.
Any help in this matter is appreciated.

Comment: We need to see the code that is causing the exception, not the code you're trying to use to catch it.

Comment: That would be correct. But at the moment i wanted to know as to why the exception is not being caught. Isn't that the purpose of __try __except block.

Comment: @ParvezAhmed: We're not telepathic.